# Переадресация на другую страницу при помощи JS

Tags: javascript

Переадресовываю на другую страницу следующим образом:

```
window.location.href="url";
```

Но так получается, что перед переадресацией браузер у меня спрашивает точно ли я хочу покинуть данную страницу.

Как от этого можно избавиться?

Comment: Не очень простая "вещь", на самом деле.. Если используете jQuery то перед переходом удаляем все обработчики -> `$(window).unbind("beforeunload");`, если нет то надо искать что отрабатывает на beforeunload и убивать его

Answer (score 2):

Используйте метод [location.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location):

```
location.assign("http://www.example.com")
```